# Entity Framework unidirectional relationship - how to specify foreign key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have the following simplified EF model:

```
public class BasePbx
{
    public int BasePbxId { get; set; }
}

public class Pbx: BasePbx
{
    public int Boo { get; set; }
}

public class BaseExtension
{
    public int BaseExtensionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int BasePbxId { get; set; }

    public BasePbx BasePbx { get; set; }
}

public class Extension : BaseExtension
{
    public Pbx Pbx { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to create two unidirectional relationships:

- from `BaseExtension` to `BasePbx` (using `BasePbxId` foreign key)
- from (derived) `Extension` to (derived) `Pbx` (using the *same* `BasePbxId` foreign key)

For the 1st relationship, EF automatically infers the foreign key property (`BasePbxId`) from the corresponding naviagtion property name `BasePbx`.

The problem is defining the 2nd relationship. EF can't use conventions to guess the foreign key, so I thought I'd state it explicitely (btw I need to express this fluently, not with attributes):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Extension>()
            .HasRequired(ext => ext.Pbx).WithMany().HasForeignKey(ext => ext.BasePbxId);
    }
```

Well... it doesn't work. The error is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The foreign key component 'BasePbxId' is not a declared property on type 'Extension'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property.

Workaround #1: I used `.Map(...) instead of`.HasForeignKey(...)` and specified the DB column name as a string, but I don't like the approach.

Workaround #2: I created a property `PbxID` in class `Extension` and mapped it to the same column as `BasePbxId` from the base class. This also looks redundantly ugly.

How can I specify the foreign key cleanly ?

Comment: Why is `BasePbxId` defined on `BaseExtension` instead of `Extension` if only `Extension` is having the foreign key defined?

Comment: @Rob The property `BasePbxId` is the foreign key for both the `BasePbx` relation in the `BaseExtension` class *and* the `Pbx` relation in the derived `Extension class`. Basically: a BasePbx can have many BaseExtensions, and a Pbx is a special type of BasePbx (has more properties, not shown) that has Extensions which are themselves special types of BaseExtension.(they too have extra properties)